# Reference to non-static member function must be called when processing callbacks inside a class

Tags: c++, c, c++11, pointers, callback

I have the following API code provided by PiGPIO library. Basically it allows you to set a callback function when the state of a pin was changed.

Normally the API looks like this:

```
typedef void (*gpio_callback_t)(int, int, uint32_t);
int gpioSetAlertFunc(int, gpio_callback_t)
```

And it can be called like this:

```
void callback_func(int pin, int NewLevel, uint32_t CurrentTicks)
{
    // Callback process
}

int main()
{
    // Setting up callback function
    gpioSetAlertFunc(10, callback_func)

    // Do stuff while callback will be called independently  
}
```

Now the code above works perfectly!

---

The big problem comes when I try to wrap this code in a C++ class. 
The class shall look like the following:

```
class Pin
{
public:
    Pin()
    {
        gpioSetAlertFunc(10, this->internal_gpio_callback) );
    }

    void internal_callback_func(int pin, int level, uint32_t tick)
    {
        cout << "New level: " << pin << " " << level;
    }
}
```

The problem is that the reference to that function is not allowed as it is not a static function. For things to be more complicated, I can't just make the callback function static. That callback function will interact a lot with the rest of the class methods and it's internal variables.

Do you know a workaround for this? Or maybe a dirty hack using pointers or something?

Comment: Usually, callbacks provide a client data pointer. With a client data pointer, you could make the callback method a static function and pass the object pointer as client data. Thus, the static method/callback function may access object members using the object pointer/client data. Without client data, the chances are very bad. The only chance, storing the object pointer in a global variable which may be used in (static) callback method.

Comment: Does each `int pin` value of the callback function map to exactly one `Pin` object?

Comment: It is important to provide **all** relevant information in the question. This question is missing an essential piece of information, namely, existence of `int gpioSetAlertFuncEx(unsigned user_gpio, gpio_callback_t f, void *userdata)`. With this piece of information known, all existing answers and comments become irrelevant.

Comment: @MaxLanghof I am not sure about that.

Comment: @n.m. At that moment I didn't know that that piece of information is relevant. But in this scenario, to make question more informative for the others, I guess we can just assume that the extended function api is not available.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An unbroken C-style callback will accept a `void*` argument to pass arbitrary user-defined data. Since this one doesn't, its a bug in the library design. Raise an issue with the library authors.

To work around this issue you need to create a *closure* as a C-compatible function. There's no way to do that is standard C or C++. There are libraries (non-standard-conforming and not portable by necessity) that solve this problem though. One such library is [GNU libffcall](https://www.gnu.org/software/libffcall/), another one is [libffi](https://github.com/atgreen/libffi/). Both allow you to create closures that behave like normal C functions.

Comment: Ok, the thing with that library is that it also have an extended version of that function which allows you to pass some user data. The function is **int gpioSetAlertFuncEx(unsigned user_gpio, gpio_callback_t f, void *userdata)**. But I still can't see the connection. How does that help me?

Comment: @caffeine Please ask a separate question about it, or search this site. There is a lot of examples. In a pinch, you create a static member function adapter, register it as a callback, and call your non-static member from there. Cast the `void*` parameter to `Pin*`.

Comment: @caffeine the best way that I know is to use `reinterpret_cast` from/to `void*`/`Pin*`

Answer (score 1):

The gpio library code has no concept of your `Pin` classes, but you cannot call your member callback function without knowing which `Pin` object to call it on. Thus, you need some (non-member) function that finds the `Pin` object to use in the function call.

It appears that this information comes in the form of the `int pin` parameter. Thus, you need a (free) function that knows about all your `Pin` objects and which pin number they have, finds the correct one and calls its callback function:

```
class Pin
{
public:
    explicit Pin(int pin);
    void internal_callback_func(int level, uint32_t tick);
private:
    int _pin;
};

// Alternatively a std::array, a std::map or similar.
std::vector<Pin> allPins;

void pinCallback(int pin, int level, uint32_t tick)
{
    Pin& pinObject = allPins[pin];
    pinObject.internal_callback_func(level, tick);
    // The Pin object presumably knows its own number.
}

Pin::Pin(int pin) : _pin(pin)
{
    gpioSetAlertFunc(_pin, pinCallback);
}

void Pin::internal_callback_func(int level, uint32_t tick)
{
    cout << "New level: " << _pin << " " << level;
}

void mainOrSo()
{
    // Create some pins and store them in the vector. Each one registers the callback on construction.
    for (int i = 0; i < 16; ++i)
       allPins.emplace_back(i);
}
```